# How to solve a circulant system of inequalities?

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, systems-of-equations, linear-programming, circulant-matrices

Let a real circulant matrix $\textbf{A}$, and a real vector $\textbf{x}$, we have $$\textbf{Ax} \ge \textbf{0}$$

The first row of $\textbf{A}$ is denoted $(a_1 a_2 \dots a_n)$.

Is there a way to express the most precise bounds $\{l_i, u_i\}$, in function of the $\{a_j\}$, such that $∀i,x_i∈[l_i,u_i]$ ?

Comment: No. E.g. when $A$ is the all-one matrix, $\ker A$ is unbounded because $x=k(1,1,\ldots,1,1-n)^T\in\ker A$ for every $k$.

Comment: If $x$ is a solution to $Ax \ge 0$, so does $\lambda x$ for any $\lambda \ge 0$. Unless you impose some other constraints on $x$, I fear you can can't get anything meaningful bounds.

Comment: Ok I got it now, thanks.